# Some nice tutorial to introduce myself into the Telepathy API?

Tags: python, c, api, bots, telepathy-python

I would like to develop a bot for Empathy, but I don't know how to get started. I've read the Telepathy wiki, but I think it's very bad documented, does anybody know any nice tutorial? Better if it uses Python or C bindings.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the telepathy-python repository's examples directory. They have quite a few listed there:
http://git.collabora.co.uk/?p=telepathy-python.git;a=tree;f=examples;h=8cede34dfe79d02dc5ce229bd2aa97934f3587c1;hb=HEAD

I also found this PDF that shows some examples with VoIP:
http://raphael.slinckx.net/files/telepathy-guadec-2007.pdf

Comment: +1 Thanks for sharing links. @aitorkun did you find more documents on telepathy? If yes please share

Answer (score 0):

The telepathy developers manual has a few python code samples: 
http://telepathy.freedesktop.org/doc/book/source-code.html